# Is it possible for Chemistry.SE & Biology.SE to support chemfig?

Tags: feature-request, latex

Chemistry.SE & Biology.SE now support [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem), is it possible to add [chem­fig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemfig/)? So we can draw organic chemical formulas and not uploading pictures.

Comment: You should post this feature requests on [meta.chemistry.se] and [meta.biology.se]. Decisions to add support for extra typesetting features are usually based on demand from the local community. The reaction here on the main meta is pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

The support for mhchem is through MathJax, but MathJax doesn't implement chemfig.  Chemfig is a complex graphics package, and is outside the scope of MathJax's support for mathematical typesetting.